# Entity Framework with ASP.NET returning null for one-to-many collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship with the following objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Program.Models
{
    public class Log
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public Log()
        {
            this.Categories = new List<Category>();
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories {get; set;}

        public LogDBContext(DbContextOptions<LogDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public LogDBContext() : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

On startup, I put the following entities into the database

```
        var cat1 = new Category { Key = "seed", Value = "seed" };
        var cat2 = new Category { Key = "seed2", Value = "seed2" };

        var log = new Log {
            Source = "seed",
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Title = "seed" };
        log.Categories.Add(cat1);
        log.Categories.Add(cat2);

        context.Logs.Add(log);

        context.SaveChanges();
```

I obtain all the entities by calling the function:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getAll")]
        public IEnumerable<Log> GetAll()
        {

            return _context.Logs.Include(c => c.Categories).AsEnumerable();


        }
```

I have tried putting the `virtual` keyword on the collection of categories (in the Log class) but no matter what I try I get `null` back for `categories` from the server.

```
[{"id":0,"source":"seed","title":"seed","timestamp":"2018-03-19T13:21:27.0034628","categories":null}]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Based on the feedback I created a constructor for `Log` that initializes the ICollection.

```
public Log()
{
    this.Categories = new List<Category>();
}
```

Now, instead of `null` I'm getting an empty list
`[{"id":0,"source":"seed","title":"seed","timestamp":"2018-03-19T13:21:27.0034628","categories":[]}]`

A step in the right direction but not there yet.

edit: For clarification, I'm using EF-Core 2.0.2
edit: Also, I am using .NET Core 2.05

"solution": I switched my project to use Asp.net with the full .Net Framework and it appears to work. I don't know why it refused to work with the asp.net with .net core.

Comment: Maybe not your problem, but you're setting the ID of your Log entry to `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`, and then when you insert the log, you are not setting the ID to any value.  This works fine if you insert 1 item, but if you insert more than one you'll get a duplicate key error

Comment: Try initializing your categories ICollection List in the Log class inside a constructor. I dont think that its initialized.

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed Thanks, I implemented a constructor for it that initializes the List. It no longer returns `null` but the list it returns is empty.

Comment: you need to create the categories object separate then add it to the Log.Categories.Add("newCategory").

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed Just tried creating the category objects then adding them to the Log object (after the logs initial creation). Unfortunately the `categories` still comes back with an empty list

Comment: Im not sure but try debbugging your seed.

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed Changed it to List, but I'm still getting back an empty categories. Also, I have visually confirmed that the seed I create is being put in the database with proper references (Categories has a reference to a log id).

Comment: First off in c# 6 you can move the `new list...` to the right hand of the `... get;} = new list`. Secondly this doesn't look like one to many. There's nothing that ties category to log. also you should probably have `virtual` on the relation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your One-to-Many relationship is not configured correctly. Write your model classes as follows:

```
public class Log
{
    public Log()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }


}

public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Log")]
    public int LogID { get; set;}
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Log Log {get; set;}
}
```

Hope, this will solve your problem..

Comment: Implemented it as you showed above. Unfortuantely `categories` is still an empty list. However, I have visually confirmed that the `Category` rows in the database reference the proper `Logs`. It seems that the relationship just isn't being retrieved when I attempt to access the logs.

Comment: Does your Category table have LogId column and Foreign key constraint for Log Id??

Comment: Delete the existing log and category tables and regenerate with my codes..Hope it will solve your problem..

Comment: yep. I have visually confirmed that the Categories table has a LogID, and that LogID is declared as a foreign key. If it's any help, here's the (generated) line that declares it as a foreign key `CONSTRAINT [FK_Categories_Logs_LogID] FOREIGN KEY ([LogID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Logs] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: I deleted the existing log and category before I ran the program with the new changes. No dice

Comment: Very strange error! Woud have been great  if had the opportunity to run your code myself and debug

Comment: Yeah, really annoying little bug. Tried a bunch of solutions online but none have helped ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. There must be some minor thing that I'm overlooking that's causing this